# Import implicit values from a companion object but not used

Tags: scala, implicit

I wrote some code which acquires some implicit values in the companion object like this:

```
package example.implicits

class Test {
  import Test.GetValue
  import Test.Implicits._

  val intV = getV[Int]
  val stringV = getV[String]

  private def getV[T](implicit getV: GetValue[T]): T = getV.value
}

object Test {
  trait GetValue[T] {
    def value: T
  }

  object Implicits {
    implicit val intValue = new GetValue[Int] {
      def value = 10
    }

    implicit val stringValue = new GetValue[String] {
      def value = "ten"
    }
  }
}
```

This piece of code cannot be compiled and the compiler complains it couldn't find the required implicit values. Note that my environment is

> scala 2.11.8 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66

However, if I use these values explicitly, nothing goes wrong:

```
class Test {
  import Test.GetValue
  import Test.Implicits._

  val intV = getV[Int](intValue)
  val stringV = getV[String](stringValue)

  private def getV[T](implicit getV: GetValue[T]): T = getV.value
}
```

Further more, if I declare new implicit values as following:

```
class Test {
  import Test.GetValue
  import Test.Implicits._

  implicit val intValue1 = intValue

  implicit val stringValue1 = stringValue

  val intV = getV[Int]
  val stringV = getV[String]

  private def getV[T](implicit getV: GetValue[T]): T = getV.value
}
```

errors will be raised because of ambiguous implicit values.

When I swap position of class Test and object Test, everything goes right:

```
object Test {
  trait GetValue[T] {
    def value: T
  }

  object Implicits {
    implicit val intValue = new GetValue[Int] {
      def value = 10
    }

    implicit val stringValue = new GetValue[String] {
      def value = "ten"
    }
  }
}

class Test {
  import Test.GetValue
  import Test.Implicits._

  val intV = getV[Int]
  val stringV = getV[String]

  private def getV[T](implicit getV: GetValue[T]): T = getV.value
}
```

So why can't scala find implicit values after I've already imported them in the first case?

And why it can do so when I swap their position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the compiler hasn't infered the type of `Test.intValue` yet at the time when it resolves the implicits in `getV[Int]`.

Just give `Test.intValue` and `Test.stringValue` their type explicitly, and your problem will be solved.

I read somewhere (sorry, can't remember where exactly), that implicit definitions should always be given an explicit type, notably to avoid this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Delighted I found this answer! I never understood why sometimes this was working for me and other times it wasn't.

Comment: For me it happened that the implicit val was named the same as another variable somewhere inside a class, and while IntelliJ was recognizing the implicit, the compiler did not find it. Renaming the implicit val to have a unique name worked.